# Asterisk15: Pj_ssl_cipher_name: symbol not found error while loading res_pjsip.so on OpenWrt

Tags: asterisk, pjsip, openwrt

I am getting the error below while loading res_pjsip.so in asterisk 15 on Openwrt. Can someone please let me know what am I missing?

```
module load res_pjsip.so

Unable to load module res_pjsip.so
Command 'module load res_pjsip.so' failed.
WARNING[19228]: loader.c:580 load_dlopen: Error loading module 'res_pjsip.so': 
Error relocating /usr/lib/asterisk/modules/res_pjsip.so: pj_ssl_cipher_name: symbol not found
WARNING[19228]: loader.c:1184 load_resource: Module 'res_pjsip.so' could not be loaded.
```

The following packages have been selected along with project libs

`asterisk15 asterisk15-pjsip asterisk13-bridge-simple asterisk13-codec-alaw asterisk13-res-rtp-asterisk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using pjproject 2.6, updating to 2.7 solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes on openwrt

Most likly - you have openssl library of other version, not same as asterisk want.